# access objects from Bluetooth manager using singleton in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am trying to create a singleton class for my BLEManager which gets called on viewdidload of the launch screen ViewController. How can I get the objects _transporter and _BLEAdapter in my view controller after the init is completed?

BLEManager.h

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject {
 BLETransporter* _transporter;
 BLEAdapter* _BLEAdapter;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) BLETransporter* transporter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BLEAdapter* BLEAdapter;

+ (id)sharedInstance;

@end
```

BLEManager.m

```
@implementation MyManager

@synthesize BLEAdapter=_BLEAdapter;
@synthesize  transporter = _BLEAdapter;

+(BLEManager*)sharedInstance{
static BLEManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});

return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
  _transporter = [BLETransporter transporterWithIdentifier:nil serviceUUIDs:serviceUUIDs];
  [_transporter connectWithBlock:^(NSInputStream * _Nullable inputStream, NSOutputStream * _Nullable outputStream) {

    if ( !inputStream )
    {
        LOG( @"Could not connect to device" );
        return;
    }

    _BLEAdapter = [BLEAdapter adapterWithInputStream:inputStream outputStream:outputStream];
    [_BLEAdapter connect];
    }];         
}
return self
}
```

Comment: Just access the properties. You should always use the properties rather than the backing iVars unless you have a specific need to bypasss the setter/getter.

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you mean like [BLEManager sharedInstance].BLEAdapter?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You can also say `BLEMananger.sharedInstance.BLEAdapter`, but by convention your properties should start with a lowercase letter (so `.bleAdapter`)

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, will fix the naming convention.  Also, do I have to initialise the BLEManager object as such, BLEManager *bleManager = [BLEManager sharedInstance], during the launch screen viewdidload and pass that object reference to different views. Or can i just call,  BLEMananger.sharedInstance, and then be able to access the its objects across all view controllers.

Comment: The first time you refer to the share instance, the singleton will be created. Be aware that you have asynchronous methods, so it will take some time before your BLE manager is rowdy to process events.